# When I run JCo adapter, it throws exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, jco

I create a JCo Adapter, and add the sapjco.jar to the server/lib directory and put the required dll file to windows\system32 directory. But it still report the exception as following in the server:
Invocation of procedure 'invokeSAPFunction' caused java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/mw/jco/JCO$Exception

What reason? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anything else in the log? This is not enough to debug.

Comment: Hi Idan, No any other log. I used in MF Studio 7.0. Here is the project the customer test: http://pan.baidu.com/s/1eQ51Mts, you can regenerate the issue

Comment: @Idan-Adar have you create a sample adatper to test this? The server only output the one-line log, it does not mean I don't want to provide the detail information. Here is the simple project for your reference: http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hq1uc52

Comment: The website requires login. Upload somewhere else, like dropbox. Also provide the .jar file I need to put in server/lib.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have uploaded it intp dropbox, you can get the project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/feuijosi7ruv2ys/Adapters.zip?dl=0 The jar file has been included in the server/lib directory

Comment: I create standalone Java project it works, but the worklight doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The JCO libraries need to be put on a path where the JRE can read them. It looks like you have put them on the server path.

There should be installations instructions included when you downloaded the JCO libraries from SAP.